# Binance API , buy crypto for crypto

Tags: api, cryptoapi, binance-api-client

Is it possible to buy cryptocurrency for another cryptocurrency (for example buy ETH using BTC) using Binance api. Cuz when i was searching inside binance api docs i didn't find anythins similar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can.

To sell BTC for ETH, you will need to place a BUY order on the symbol `ETHBTC`.  In order to create an order from API, you can use the general endpoint `POST /api/v3/order`.  Hope this can be helpful.